# How can I uninstall Ubuntu without Dual booting

Tags: uninstall

It's an old computer so I decided I'd mess around with Ubuntu and try it out, but now I have a use for it and would prefer it be windows. However, since updating last week Ubuntu has overwritten my ability to boot from a CD and I can't figure out a way to get rid of it.

Comment: An old computer you may also suffer from a weak BIOS battery. After each power off default BIOS setting will then be loaded. You will have to replace the battery then.

Comment: Make and model of your system? Does it have USB ports?

Answer (score 1):

When you first turn on your PC, the Hard Disk spins up as the Computer finds out that it is something other than a lump of metal and plastic, the information for this is stored in the BIOS, there is usually a screen which flashes up for a couple of seconds or so. The following instructions only work if they are carried out whilst this screen is showing.

Depending on your PC and how much you have played with it in the past, depends whether you will receive a message on boot at the bottom of the screen or not, however, if no message is shown, press the following keys, one at a time <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd>, it is usually one of these keys to access the BIOS Screen.

Once in the BIOS, use the arrow keys to navigate. Press the <kbd>></kbd> key until you get to the Boot tab. Next use the <kbd>V</kbd> key to highlight the CD/DVD player, then make sure that it appears above the other disks by pressing (usually) <kbd>+</kbd> key.

Once the CD/DVD player is at the top of the list, Click on the <kbd>></kbd>, highlight the Save and Exit option and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will save the new configuration and reboot the system. If your Windows CD is in the CD drive, it will (should) boot that rather than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

When you turn on your computer it will load up a screen at the bottom it will say something like Press Del to open BIOS, When you open the BIOS depending on what type of motherboard you have you can change your boot order. The most useful order is probably. 
First boot: CD
Second Boot: HDD
Third Boot:Anything you want. (In case for some reason the HDD is not there this will take effect.)